# Live preview with React, Html2Canvas and JsPDF

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I am creating a resume-generating web app using react, html2canvas and jspdf. I want to get a live preview of the pdf when someone submits a form. I spent several hours looking for a solution to it.
But bad luck.
This site has a great example of what I want [ [Here](https://jobii.be/) ]. Does anyone have an idea, Link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I understand that you don't need `jspdf` for live preview as you just need to display image of the resume created using `html2canvas`.
[Check the implementation here](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/nffnq3wr/)

`jspdf` is only required when you need to download it as pdf then you can convert the image generated by `html2canvas` to pdf using `jspdf`

**Update**

To hide the HTML elements and only show the canvas you can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/singhsterabhi/crLh36z9/28/).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I know that already. I can use the canvas as a preview. But how can I hide the div elements? Only canvas without HTML preview?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import { PDFObject } from "react-pdfobject";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

const PreView = () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
  const url = doc.output("bloburi");

  return <PDFObject url={url} />;
};

export default PreView;
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation?